# Implement word2vec in Keras

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras, theano, word2vec

I would like to implement word2vec algorithm in keras, Is this possible? 
How can I fit the model? Should I use custom loss function?

Comment: I found this before I ask, but It's too old and messy. Here is a newer implementation: https://github.com/SimonPavlik/word2vec-keras-in-gensim/blob/keras106/word2veckeras/word2veckeras.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this possible?

You've already answered it yourself: yes. In addition to [`word2veckeras`](https://github.com/niitsuma/word2vec-keras-in-gensim), which uses `gensim`, here's another [CBOW implementation](https://github.com/abaheti95/Deep-Learning/tree/master/word2vec/keras) that doesn't have extra dependencies (just in case, I'm not affiliated with this repo). You can use them as examples.

> How can I fit the model?

Since the training data is the large corpus of sentences, the most convenient method is [`model.fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), which "fits the model on data generated batch-by-batch by a Python generator". The generator runs indefinitely yielding `(word, context, target)` CBOW (or SG) tuples, but you manually specify `sample_per_epoch` and `nb_epoch` to limit the training. This way you decouple sentence analysis (tokenization, word index table, sliding window, etc) and actual keras model, plus [save a lot of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628903/performance-advantages-to-iterators).

> Should I use custom loss function?

CBOW minimizes the distance between the predicted and true distribution of the center word, so in the simplest form `categorical_crossentropy` will do it.
If you implement [negative sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860652/word2vec-negative-sampling-in-layman-term), which is a bit more complex, yet much more efficient, the loss function changes to [`binary_crossentropy`](https://keras.io/losses/). Custom loss function is unnecessary.

For anyone interested in details of math and probabilistic model, I highly recommend CS224D class by Stanford. [Here is the lecture notes](https://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/notes1.pdf) about word2vec, CBOW and Skip-Gram.

Another useful reference: [word2vec implementation](https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec) in pure `numpy` and `c`.

Comment: It was an old question but thank you for your detailed answer!