# What is the "original" skip-gram model?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

The skip-gram model I've commonly seen is a 3-layer neural network with a hidden projection/embedding layer. The embedding layer has embedding weight matrix, which will be eventually the embedding vectors of the words in corpus. The softmax layer (output layer) also have a weight matrix, which do not directly represent any words. Here I call this model skip-gram **model 1**.

[image]

I am reading a [book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/natural-language-processing-tensorflow). The book mentioned there is an original skip-gram algorithm, which is different to the above one. Here I call this "original" skip-gram model as skip-gram **model 2**. According to this book,

> The skip-gram algorithm discussed up to this point in the book is
>   actually an improvement over the original skip-gram algorithm proposed
>   in the original paper by Mikolov and others, published in 2013. In
>   this paper, the algorithm did not use an intermediate hidden layer to
>   learn the representations. In contrast, the original algorithm used
>   two different embedding or projection layers (the input and output
>   embeddings in Figure 4.1) and defined a cost function derived from the
>   embeddings themselves:

[image]

**My first question is where can I find the "original paper"?** It seems in the paper *Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space* the skip-gram model is the model 1, not the above original model 2.

There are some dicussions where people say the softmax nomalization computes vector similarities. For example, in [mbatchkarov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860652/word2vec-negative-sampling-in-layman-term), he gave explanation for the softmax computation:

> The numerator is basically the similarity between words c (the
>   context) and w (the target) word. The denominator computes the
>   similarity of all other contexts c1 and the target word w.

**Second question: Is that the "original" skip-gram model 2?** Because in the common skip-gram model 1, the output layer weights are just neural network weights, not vector representations for words.

Comment: Did you find it? I am also searching for it.

Comment: @MasayoMusic No, I didnot.